# Why are the T4 outputs being created then deleted?

Tags: visual-studio, t4

I have a T4 that is generating multiple .html files.

After creating them all it then deletes them. I have seen the files create in both explorer and VS2010 ultimate (the solution explorer bar grows and then shrinks right back).

I have modified Oleg Synch's [updated multiple output code](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/) as follows:

```
ProjectItem GetTemplateItem(DTE dte)
{
 return   // Find the .tt file's ProjectItem
 dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile);
}

void SaveOutput(string outputFileName,List<string> savedOutputs)
 {
  string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
  string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);  
  var text= this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
  WriteDiagnosticLine("Writing:"+text.Length+" characters");
  File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath,text);
  this.GenerationEnvironment = new StringBuilder();  

  ProjectItem templateProjectItem = GetTemplateItem(Dte);

  templateProjectItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(outputFilePath);  

  savedOutputs.Add(outputFileName);

  WriteDiagnosticLine("Added:"+outputFileName);
 }

void WriteDiagnosticLine(string line)
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

the initial code to set `Dte` is

```
bool AlwaysKeepTemplateDirty = true;
DTE Dte;
var serviceProvider = Host as IServiceProvider;

    if (serviceProvider != null) {
        Dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
    }

    // Fail if we couldn't get the DTE. This can happen when trying to run in TextTransform.exe
    if (Dte == null) {
        throw new Exception("T4Generator can only execute through the Visual Studio host");
    }
```

it happens whether I make a change and hit save, or right click the .tt file and say run custom tool.

In case it's helpful here's my tt declaration:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #>
```

Comment: missed an include in the paste: `<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>`

Comment: Does that template use the same log file (so that it can remove items when it's supposed to) that the linq generator does? If so, what does that have in it, and is it writeable when you run your custom tool?

Comment: I'm not sure what that template is, it's there by default when I create a new script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing

```
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
```

seems to have solved it. pretty bizarre.